# check if price is being displayed tax included

Tags: magento-1.9, price, product-view

I am overriding the price.phtml template because I need to display a label. When in the backend, the "Tax Display Type" setting catalog products is set to 'Tax Included' but I don't know how to perform this check.

Answer (score 7):

From what I can tell, you're trying to get the configuration setting which determines how Taxes are displayed in the Catalog in Magento. This setting can be found in System -> Configuration -> (Sales)Tax -> Price Display Settings

If you look at the dropdown for "Display Product Price in Catalog" you can see that the `<select>` has three values of 1,2,3 and an id of `tax_display_type`.

Now to take all this information we found and translate it into code:

Retrieving any data that this field stores in the database uses the following code:

```
$tax_display_type = Mage::getStoreConfig(
                   'tax/display/type',
                   Mage::app()->getStore()
               );
```

This will return 1,2 or 3 depending on what you have set that dropdown to. As an aside, these settings are stored in the `core_config_data` table under `path` = `tax/display/type`.